# Weird tags in bad formatted question

Tags: bug, status-declined

Right now I've seen [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/24930065/1) with really "special" formatting, that had six tags. Three of them are [linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linux), [linker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linker) and [runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/runtime), the other three are **the exact same** tags, but with a weird encoding.

The bug is, that they are in fact recognized as the same tags (same amount of followers and questions), but when clicking on them they lead to different pages.

Comment: Not a weird encoding - just a different set of Latin code points (they are all full width Latin characters - in the 65nnn range).

Comment: Well, but shouldn't they be considered equal and link to the same page, as well as only be shown once?

Comment: Sure, not saying this isn't a bug, just that this isn't an encoding issue, per se.

Comment: I did actually not say that the encoding was the issue, but you are right, the encoding is not weird, just unexpected on the internet...

Comment: looks like someone with a japanese keyboard layout wrote that

Comment: I̼͈͔͈̬̮̪ͣ ̳̲̘̩̠͊d͈̺͇̠ỉ͔d̰̼̯̫̲̆̊ͧn͙̻̖͔̙̒͐̊̓͒ͯͅ'̹̮̱̮̄̈̚t̞̥̬͉̗͋ͮ͆̎ͮ ̺͚̝ͤ̅̏̓̈́ͅs̜̞̞̐͒̽̅̒e̹̘͉̭ͩeͯ̄ͧͭͅ ̠̦̄̎̔͗̾̿̈́a̱͔̓ͨ͌͋ͬn̪̎̒̆yͬ̋ ͈̹̹͉͚̼ͬ̑w͐̌͗̉ẽ̞̮̒͌̌ͩ̈́i͐̃̽̑͐r̞͔̐ͮ̃ͦ̌ͨd̦̱̰̩̼̽̽̆̎ͭ̇ͅ ͇̹͈̈́̓ͣ͒͒ͦf̘̻̈́o̫͎ͤ̑͐r͈̻̥͂ͪ̔̽ͩ̆͗m̘̭̣̓̊̍̓̓̋ͯa͍̱͎̻̖͍̬͛tͨͫ̋ͪͭ͊ͦt͈̫̥͐̈̋ͯi͎ͣ̇ͯ̆̓n̆̾̑̉͋̏ͥg̫̤̙̻̮͉͗ͫͭ̓̓̅.͇̮̜̟̪͉̣

Comment: The <center> cannot hold it is too late.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Though rather startling, we will not be fixing the issue at the time being.

In 5 years, this is the first occurrence and the community fixed the issue very quickly (and it didn't have any adverse effect anywhere), so unless this becomes a common issue, we would rather focus our efforts elsewhere.

Thanks for reporting!

Comment: Sometimes, it's really the proper choice to ignore all the intricacies of unicode and pretend they don't exist. As long as you know, it's not an issue and you made a conscious choice.